# File Manager for Gnome that matches the feature-set of KDE Dolphin File Manager

Tags: linux, gnome, kde, manjaro, file-manager

Is there a File manager for Gnome that is comparable to the KDE Dolphin file manager?

I am unable to use the Gnome file manager to drag and drop files into an audio VST's interface but it works using Dolphin.

The appearance of Dolphin does not seem to be easily configurable in Gnome and it does not fit in with my desktop theme.

Comment: Does it work in Dolphin while using KDE or Gnome? Who is drawing the desktop?

Comment: it works from Dolphin in both KDE and Gnome. I'm running Xorg if that's what you mean by drawing the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out configuring dolphin is quite simple in gnome using kvantum and qt5ct.